# How to remove sublists with two consecutive identical digits?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a number `444123`. The permutations of its digits are, for example,

```
{{4,4,4,3,2,1},{4,1,2,4,4,3},{4,1,4,3,4,2}}
```

I want to remove any permutations with consecutively repeated 4. So the filtered sublist must become

```
{{4,1,4,3,4,2}}
```

as `{4,4,4,3,2,1}` that contains `4,4,4`  and `{4,1,2,4,4,3}` that contains `4,4` are removed.

## Attempt

```
DeleteCases[Permutations[IntegerDigits@444123], 4..]
```

But it produces unfiltered output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[{___, 4, 4, ___}]@Permutations[IntegerDigits@444123]
```

> ```
> {{4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3}, {4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2}, {4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4}, 
>  {4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3}, {4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4}, 
>  {4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1}, {4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4}, {4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4}, 
>  {4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1}, {4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4},
>  {4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4}, {1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4},
>  {2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to use `..`?

Comment: @WissenMachtFrei, you can use `DeleteCases[{___, 4, 4 .. , ___}]` or `DeleteCases[{___, Repeated[4, {2, Infinity}], ___}]`

Answer (score 6):

We can also fill the gap of 1,2,3 by using 4.( here we replace 1,2,3 by a,b,c and replace 4 by x)

```
original = Permutations[{a, b, c}]
gapPositions = Subsets[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {3}]
Flatten[Outer[Insert[#1, x, #2] &, original, gapPositions, 1], 1]
```

```
{{x, a, x, b, x, c}, {x, a, x, b, c, x}, {x, a, b, x, c, x}, {a, x, b,
   x, c, x}, {x, a, x, c, x, b}, {x, a, x, c, b, x}, {x, a, c, x, b, 
  x}, {a, x, c, x, b, x}, {x, b, x, a, x, c}, {x, b, x, a, c, x}, {x, 
  b, a, x, c, x}, {b, x, a, x, c, x}, {x, b, x, c, x, a}, {x, b, x, c,
   a, x}, {x, b, c, x, a, x}, {b, x, c, x, a, x}, {x, c, x, a, x, 
  b}, {x, c, x, a, b, x}, {x, c, a, x, b, x}, {c, x, a, x, b, x}, {x, 
  c, x, b, x, a}, {x, c, x, b, a, x}, {x, c, b, x, a, x}, {c, x, b, x,
   a, x}}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Using `Sequence..` functionality:**

```
plist = Permutations@IntegerDigits@444123;

Extract[plist, 
 SequenceCases[#, {4, 4}] & /@ plist  // Position[#, {}] &]

Pick[plist, SequenceCount[#, {4, 4}] & /@ plist, 0]

SequenceReplace[#, {4, 4} :> Nothing] & /@ plist // 
 Select[Length@# == 6 &]
```

> {{4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3}, {4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2}, {4, 1, 4,
> 3, 2, 4}, {4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 1, 4,
> 3}, {4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1}, {4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4}, {4,
> 2, 1, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 4, 1,
> 2, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1}, {4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 4, 2,    4},
> {4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4}, {1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4}, {2,    4,
> 1, 4, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 2, 4,
> 1, 4}}

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `Repeated` matches one or more. Then you want to match lists, so

```
DeleteCases[Permutations[IntegerDigits@444123], {___, 4, 4 .., ___}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Permutations[IntegerDigits@444123]//Pick[#,Length@Split[#,#1==#2==4&]&/@#,6]&
```

> {{4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3}, {4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2}, {4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4}, {4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3}, {4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1}, {4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4}, {4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1}, {4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4}, {1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4}}

Answer (score 4):

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
list = Permutations @ IntegerDigits @ 444123;

list /. {___, 4, 4, ___} :> Nothing
```

gives

```
{{4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3}, {4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2},
 {4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4}, {4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4},
 {4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3}, {4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1},
 {4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4}, {4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4},
 {4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1},
 {4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4},
 {1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4},
 {2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Pick`:

```
list = Permutations[IntegerDigits@444123];

Pick[#, AllTrue[SplitBy[#, Repeated], DuplicateFreeQ[#] &] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3}, {4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2}, 
   {4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4}, {4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4}, 
   {4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3}, {4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1}, 
   {4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4}, {4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4},
   {4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1},
   {4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4}, 
   {1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4}, 
   {2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4}}*)
```

Another option, although slow, is to use `Select` and `SequenceCases`:

```
Select[list, SequenceCases[#, {___, a_, a_, ___}] == {} &]

 (*{{4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3}, {4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2}, 
   {4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4}, {4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4}, 
   {4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3}, {4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1}, 
   {4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4}, {4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4},
   {4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1},
   {4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4}, 
   {1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4}, 
   {2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4}}*)
```